# Food safety with broken glass in dried tomatoes

Tags: food-safety

I have a very large jar of dried tomatoes and somehow the lid broke so that broken glass fell into the tomatoes. Is there any safe way to be able to eat them?

Answer (score 12):

Simple, the answer is no. Throw them right in the trash.

Comment: Listen to this guy - toss them. Glass is basically impossible to 100% get out of food. Even if you DO happen to get it all out, you can't ever really KNOW that you got it all out...

Comment: And internal perforation is no joke... leads to internal bleeding and/or internal scarring.